# python: bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I use pyenv to manage python installations but this morning after I installed `graphviz` with Homebrew any commands which use python started to break with the error `bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. For example, when I run `docker-compose`:

```
/Users/hammer/Library/Python/3.7/bin/docker-compose: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It's true that `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7` doesn't exist, but I don't know where this value is configured? What is pointing at it? Python works fine for me otherwise:

```
% which python
/Users/.../.pyenv/shims/python
% python --version
Python 3.8.5
% python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm running MacOS 10.15.5. I've tried reinstalling `pyenv` and python

Comment: Does `brew update && brew upgrade` help?

Comment: So I think what happened is something (maybe `graphviz`, don't really know) updated my python to 3.8. I went around, found python3.7 folders and deleted them. That fixed it.

Comment: The way to investigate something like that is to see if your original python is a symlink, and if so where it points to; and so on. Take the path you found with `which` and use `ls -l /Users/.../.pyenv/shims/python` to see what the link points to.

Comment: I had a similar issue that resulted from reinstalling homebrew. I fixed it by doing `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python` and `brew install python`, as well as `brew link --overwrite <formula>` for any stale formulas I had installed. I learned all of this by running `brew doctor`.